# event on finger release

Tags: ios, uikit

I have 5 images on my `UIViewcontroller` in `Storyboard`. 4 of the five images can be moved (graph 1,2,3,4) with the finger on the screen. Then I created an if statement: if I drag one of the images on the fixed one (final graph), on a label appears "text". In my statement I wrote intercept. The only problem is that the text on the label appears as soon as the two images intercept. But I want to make it appear when the user removes the finger to "drop" the image. how can I do that?

Here is the code:

```
//image movement
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

   UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

   if ([touch view] == graph1) {
      CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
      graph1.center = location;
      [self interceptofgraphs]; 
   }

   if ([touch view] == graph2) {
      CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
      graph2.center = location;
     [self interceptofgraphs];
   }

   if ([touch view] == graph3) {
      CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
      graph3.center = location;
      [self interceptofgraphs];
   }

   if ([touch view] == graph4) {
      CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
      graph4.center = location;
      [self interceptofgraphs];
   }
}

-(void)interceptofgraphs {

   if (CGRectIntersectsRect(graph2.frame, finalgraph.frame))
      graphlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Right answer. Well done!!"];

   if (CGRectIntersectsRect(graph1.frame, finalgraph.frame))
      graphlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Wrong!! not at all."];

   if (CGRectIntersectsRect(graph3.frame, finalgraph.frame))
      graphlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Wrong!! Try again"];

   if (CGRectIntersectsRect(graph4.frame, finalgraph.frame))
       graphlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Wrong!! NO"];
}
```

Thanks to all of you who answer!!

Comment: Retagged; not an XCode problem. XCode is just the IDE, and this question has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

  //we'll almost certainly need a location of touch
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

  //we store the reference of a view that was touched into touchedView
  UIView *touchedView = [touch view];

  //if view that was touched is one of the views we're interested in
  if ((touchedView == graph1)||(touchedView == graph2)||
      (touchedView == graph3)||(touchedView == graph4)) {

    //we move it's center
    //since the touchedView hold's a reference to the view that
    //was touched - we're moving the right view for sure
    touchedView.center = location;    
  }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  //we only want to check whitch view was moved at the end 
  //when user releases the touch
  [self interceptofgraphs];
}
```

Comment: @Alessandro: added some comments